# How to fix TypeError: vowels () missing required positional argument: 'filehandle'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that reads the contents of a text file into a string

```
def vowels(filehandle):
    num_vowel = 0
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
    for c in filehandle:
        if c in vowels:
            num_vowel = num_vowel+1
    return num_vowel

def consonants(filehandle):
    num_con = 0
    for c in filehandle:
        if c >= 'a' and c <= 'z':
            if c not in vowels:
                num_con = num_con+1
        elif c>='A' and c<='Z':
            if c not in vowels:
                num_con = num_con+1
    return num_con

def case(filehandle):
    uppercase = 0
    lowercase = 0
    for c in filehandle:
        if c>='a' and c<='z':
            uppercase=uppercase+1
        elif c>='A' and c<= 'Z':
            lowercase=lowecase+1
    return uppercase, lowercase

def main():
    vowel = vowels()
    consonants = consonants()
    uppercase, lowercase = case()
    try:
        filename=input('Enter name of text file: ')
        filehandle=open('words.txt', 'r')

        print('Vowels:', vowels)
        print('Consonants:', consonants)
        print('Uppercase:', uppercase)
        print('Lowercase:', lowercase)

        filehandle.close()
    except IOError:
        print('FILE NOT FOUND')


main()
```

As I try to run the program, it gives me this error

```
line 31, in main
    vowel = vowels()
TypeError: vowels() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filehandle'
```

I'm still new to python and using functions so if you could put it in terms where anybody can understand it, that would be much appreciated

Comment: If you define a function with a parameter `vowels(filehandle)` you can't call `vowels()` without putting some value in there.

Comment: you need a parameter

Comment: Instead of passing the filehandle to your functions, you will need to pass the text of the file. `for c in filehandle:` gets the `line` of the file in `c` (not the character the following lines test for).  `def vowels(filehandle):` would be `def vowels(text):` in your functions. In `main()` then, you'll need to say something like `text = filehandle.read()` to get the needed text of the file (all in 1 variable).

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `vowels()` states that it requires a parameter:

```
def vowels(filehandle):
```

But then inside `main()` you're calling it without a parameter:

```
vowel = vowels()
```